# Find electron-hole recombination rate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

In an n-type semiconductor, the thermal equilibrium electron concentration (n<sub>0</sub>=10<sup>15</sup>/cm<sup>3</sup>) and the intrinsic carrier concentration (n<sub>i</sub>=10<sup>10</sup>/cm<sup>3</sup>). The mean life time of minority carriers is 1us. The steady state excess hole concentration due to constant light illumination is 4*10<sup>5</sup>/cm<sup>3</sup>. Under illumination, the steady state electron-hole concentration is-

My attempt:

At steady state since generation rate is equal to recombination rate, I found out recombination rate by dividing excess hole concentration by the given hole lifetime. I got 400 cm<sup>-3</sup>/ns but the answer provided by the instructor is 500 cm<sup>-3</sup>/ns.

An observation:

If I add thermal equilibrium hole value to excess hole concentration then I get the required answer of 500. But recombination rate is given by excess minority concentration. So why I need this addition?